# react-native-router-flux - Resetting navigation stack in tab

Tags: react-native

### What we want

We use `react-native-router-flux` in our application and find ourself in a situation where we need to reset the navigation stack (at least) for one tab. This is our scene structure:

```
tabs
  listTab
    listView
    recordingView
  creationTab
    recordView
    descriptionView
    publishView
```

Concretely, our application lets users create and view recordings. There's a `listTab`, with two sub-scenes (list of recordings and view a single recording) and a tab for creating (`creationTab`) recordings with several steps (`recordView`, `descriptionView`, `publishView`). After the last step, the recording is `publish`ed and we redirect to the `viewRecording` scene for that recording in the `listTab`.
When pressing the `creationTab` again, we would like to get back to the first scene of the creation process again, but instead we of course land on the last step (`publishView`) again.

### What we tried

After reading through the documentation and issues connected to this, we figured the option `reset` might help us. However, if we try to add `type='reset'` to the props of `creationTab`, when pressing the tab, all other tab icons disappear (as documented in [this issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/467)).

So instead, we then tried to set the `type` of our push from `publishView` to `recordingView` to `reset`, but that also did not work (although the right action is dispatched and the `back` button is removed on the new scene, when hitting the `recordingTab` icon again, we still get back to our old `publishView`).

We also though about using `Switch`es, to unmount the components but it doesn't seem like this is how they were intended to be used...

### Versions

- `react-native`: 0.30.0
- `react-native-router-flux`: 3.32.0

We're now getting a bit desperate after days spent on issues like this and similar ones and I am not sure how we should proceed. Has anybody experienced similar problems or found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. As a temporary workaround, I do not use the `reset` option but instead follow the redirection immediately with a `pop` action.

In my case, my view is only one level deep so this is not too dirty. I'll look for a cleaner solution but I hope it can help in the meantime.

`react-native`: 0.35.0-rc

`react-native-router-flux`: 3.35.0

Comment: Yes this is a great solution

Comment: redirection...? something like this `Actions.pop(); Actions.scene();`?

Comment: @Lughino Well in my case, from a given view, I want to go back to a project page, which is included in a Activity view. I will do this way:
`NavigationActions.activity();
NavigationActions.pop();
NavigationActions.projectPage({ projectId });` The link to the issue in the question might also help you.

Comment: @ArthurParmentier thanks for the reply!
My problem is to reset the view when user select the tab.
The way you have explained, unfortunately, is not compatible with this.
Thanks for the explanation anyway!